# Работа с файлами и строками в си

Tags: c, файлы

Здравствуйте. Возникла проблема при работе с файлами, предоставляю код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fp2;
    if ((fp = fopen("input", "r")) != NULL)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%d %d\n", &a, &b);
        printf("yes.\n");
    }
    else { printf("no"); }
    fclose(fp);
    fp2 = fopen("output", "w");
    fprintf(fp2, "%d %d\n", a, b);
    fclose(fp2);
    exit(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Опишу ситуацию. Есть 2 файла: input и output. В первом представлены несколько строк в каждой из которых есть два числа,разделенных пробелом, скажем как в примере ниже:
5 6
7 15
9 568
23 75

Задача вывести в файл output то же самое что и в input, но при компиляции кода выше в output выводится только первая строка, т.е. 5 6 а остальных нет. Что добавить или убрать в коде, чтобы решить проблему? Спасибо.

Comment: Цикл нужно добавить

Comment: Ваш код делает ровно то, что и должен: читает два числа из первого файла (5 6) и пишет их во второй. Как вы его написали, так он и работает.

Comment: Цикл while? Можно здесь поподробнее...

Comment: Подробнее про циклы почитайте в учебниках.

Comment: Хорошо, я  понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы читаете из input только первые два символа. Лучше всего в вашем случае воспользоваться ф-цией `getc ()` или `getchar ()` - этого для вашей задачи вполне хватит. Ну и цикл конечно. Что-то типа:

```
while ((ch = getc (input)) != EOF) {
    putc (ch, output);
}
```

Comment: Добавьте `int ch;` перед примером кода. А то ведь ТС решит, что раз читаем посимвольно, то `char ch;` будет правильно (и ошибется)

Comment: вообще-то ch - это и есть char! Поэтому-то и используются ф-ции getc & putc.

Comment: Прочтите (только внимательно) [man getchar](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) и обязательно обдумайте, каким образом можно прочесть **любой символ**, а  **EOF** будет отличен от них? А может быть будет лучше, если сами  попробуете реализовать какую-то часть libio (FILE \* ввод-вывод, частью которой являются упомянутые вами getc & putc)

Comment: EOF как правило, возвращает -1, что вполне входит в диапазон char. Все символы, встречающиеся в файле - априори будут считываеться ф-цией, а когда будет достигнут конец файла - будет возвращена EOF. В чем тут может быть проблема?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, по стандарту char может быть как знаковым, так и беззнаковым

Comment: Точнее в стандарте точно не прописано, каким он должен быть по дефолту - это уже ваши проблемы. Если у вас тип char по дефолту беззнаковый - то просто пишите signed char - вот и все.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, в самом деле EOF это -1. А теперь прикиньте, если вы возвращаете `char`, то как отличить `0xff` из файла от -1? Вот поэтому фукции и возвращают int (если интересно, то там внутри стоит `return c & 0xff`, отрезающий расширение знакового бита)

Comment: Ну ка, расскажите мне пожалуйста, и как мы можем получить байт с 0xff из файла, а после этого сравните ваш ответ с условием задачи.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, байт `0xff` в этой задаче? Запросто. Занесем его туда (в файл "input") любым двоичным редактором (или текстовым в винде. Это код буквы `я` в кодировке cp1251). И дело тут не в условиях задачи, а в понимании базовых вещей.

Comment: Итак, как я понял для возврата -1 нужно всего-то реализация char как unsigned char, двоичный редактор, кодировка cp1251 и буква я, какая каким-то неведомым образом должна затесаться в файл задачи, в которой по условию даны лишь цифровые значения. Мне одному кажется, что вы слишком усложняете? Я не говорил, что мой способ единственно верный и безоговорочно верен всегда и при любых условиях - ЧИТАЙТЕ МОЙ ОТВЕТ!!! Черным по белому написано: этого для вашей задачи вполне хватит.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a, b;
FILE *fp;
FILE *fp2;
if (((fp = fopen("input", "r")) != NULL) && ((fp2 = fopen("output", "r")) != NULL))
{
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d %d\n", &a, &b) == 2)
        fprintf(fp2,"%d %d\n",a,b);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
}
```

Comment: А если в строке будет только одно число?

Comment: Если `fp` откроется, а `fp2` - нет, то кто будет закрывать `fp`?

Comment: Строка предполагает наличие именно двух чисел